# Как вывести пустые не достающие объекты в массив?

Tags: vue.js

Я использую pinia , а в ней я не могу использовать computed , в чем суть вопрос , у меня в сторедже pinia хранится массив , мне надо сделать так , что если в данном массиве объектов меньше 7 , то оно должно добавит не достающие кол-во пустых объектов , вот метод и сам сторедж

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'

export const useBusinessStore = defineStore('business', {
   state: () => {
      return {
         orderingProducts: [
            {idOrder: 1, productName: 'Cок', countProduct: 10, orderAmount: 10000, deliveryPrice: 500},
            {idOrder: 2, productName: 'Кола', countProduct: 10, orderAmount: 10000, deliveryPrice: 500},
            {idOrder: 3, productName: 'Лимонад', countProduct: 10, orderAmount: 10000, deliveryPrice: 500},
            {idOrder: 4, productName: 'Квас', countProduct: 10, orderAmount: 10000, deliveryPrice: 500},
            {idOrder: 5, productName: 'Фанта', countProduct: 10, orderAmount: 10000, deliveryPrice: 500}
         ],
      }                          
   },
   actions: {
      getPerfectOrderProduct() {
         if (this.orderingProducts.length < 7) {
            const numberOfMissingElements = 7 - this.orderingProducts.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < numberOfMissingElements; i++) {
               console.log(numberOfMissingElements)
               this.orderingProducts.push({
                  idOrder: null,
                  productName: '',
                  countProduct: null,
                  orderAmount: null,
                  deliveryPrice: null,
               });
            }
         }
      },
   },
})
```

вот так я объявляю pinia в компоненте

```
<script setup>
import { useBusinessStore } from '@/stores/PropertyStore/business'

const bizStore = useBusinessStore()
</script>
```

Вот так вывожу данный массив

```
<div class="table__main-item deliver" v-for="(order, index) in bizStore.orderingProducts" :key="index">
            <div class="table__main-block">{{order.idOrder}}</div>
            <div class="table__main-block">{{order.productName}}</div>
            <div class="table__main-block">{{order.idOrder != null ? order.orderAmount / order.countProduct : null}}</div>
            <div class="table__main-block">{{order.countProduct}}</div>
            <div class="table__main-block">{{order.orderAmount}}</div>
            <div class="table__main-block">{{order.deliveryPrice}}</div>
         </div>
```

Подумал что я могу сделать в computed метод вот такой

```
computed: {
         perfectOrderProduct() {
            this.bizStore.getPerfectOrderProduct()
            return this.bizStore.orderingProducts;
         }
      }
```

и заменить в v-for bizStore.orderingProducts на perfectOrderProduct чтобы оно сразу выводило не достающее кол-во объектов, если их меньше 7 , но оно ругается на

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getPerfectOrderProduct')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getPerfectOrderProduct')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array

Comment: @Михаил вот я использую 
```
const numberOfMissingElements = 7 - this.orderingProducts.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < numberOfMissingElements; i++) {
               console.log(numberOfMissingElements)
               this.orderingProducts.push({
                  idOrder: null,
                  productName: '',
                  countProduct: null,
                  orderAmount: null,
                  deliveryPrice: null,
               });
            }
```

Comment: а что вы делаете знаком "/" в условии - order.idOrder != null ? order.orderAmount / order.countProduct : null Может деление на ноль у вас появляется

Comment: Делю две переменные друг на друга , я сделал тернарное условие , что если у меня добавиться пустой объект в массив , то все его значения будут равны null , значит деление выдаст мне Nan

Comment: Я наверное не совсем понимаю что вы хотите под "вывести пустые" - так как {{null}} и не будет выводиться (если в условии появится). Поэтому для ПОКАЗА можно в условии использовать строку  типа : 'No'  или "0' или т.п. что вам захочется. 
И если вы получаете объект с данными из Базы или Форму - не проще установить для всех параметров дефолтные значения - и получать и не проверять есть они или нет.

Comment: Для чего я это делаю , так задумано дизайном  , у меня это таблица и для красоты надо сделать так , что если длина массива меньше 7 , то оно вычислит не достающие кол-во до 7 и при помощи for в метод должно запушить столько же объектов , сколько не хватает для 7. Подразумеваю под пустыми это означает , что все переменные в данном объекты будут пустые

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен , здесь выводило ошибку , потому что bizstor был не виден

```
computed: {
         perfectOrderProduct() {
            const bizStore = useBusinessStore()
            bizStore.getPerfectOrderProduct()
            return bizStore.orderingProducts;
         }
      }
```